# Create a frequency diagram using a dataframe in Pandas (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I currently have a list of the number of items and their frequency stored in a data frame called transactioncount_freq.

```
Item    Frequency
0   1   3474
1   2   2964
2   3   1532
3   4   937
4   5   360
5   6   168
6   7   57
7   8   25
8   9   5
9   10  5
10  11  3
11  12  1
```

How would I make a bar chart using the `item` values as the x axis and the `frequency` values as the y axis using pandas and matplotlib.pyplot?

Comment: Can't you just `df.plot(kind='bar')` ?

Comment: Use `df.plot(x='Item',y='Frequency',kind='bar')`

Comment: Try `transactioncount_freq.plot.bar(x='Item', y='Frequency')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot it easily like this

```
transactioncount_freq.plot(x='Item', y='Frequency', kind='bar')
```

[image]